# How can I make money selling my ERC20 token?

Tags: ether, tokens, erc-20

So let say I bought $2000 worth of Ethereum at $846 ETH price in GDAX. By the time I exchanged my ETH in Binance to my token and placed it in MyEtherWallet Ledger Nano S, the value of the token is around $1990 for example.

Lets say in a few weeks the price of Ethereum falls to $830 and that exact same day I decide to sell my token and the value of my token according to EtherScan is $2500.

Now if I want to sell the token and take my $500 pre tax profit how can I do it?

By the time I exchange my token back to ETH in Binance since I made an extra $490 with the token, when I exchange it to ETH will my amount of ETH owned go up to be equivolent to the $2480 with profit I made or how does it work with the exchange where Ethereum will be given to me that says I made the $490 extra even though the price of Ethereum dropped and I'd be selling it for the dropped price of $830?

Comment: I don't quite follow the last part of this, but this sounds like an accounting question, not an Ethereum question. To simplify the math, choose a base currency (ETH, USD, pork bellies) and stick with it for all your accounting.

Comment: No I'm just saying Lets say I bought 2.5 ETH for $2000. Exchanged that 2.5 ETH in Binance for it's equivalent amount of OmiseGo tokens (for example) Lets say 3000 OMG tokens.  A few weeks later the value of the 3000 owned OMG tokens goes up to $2500. Now when I exc hange those 3000 OMG tokens, in Binance will it now show that I  have more ETH for to make up for that extra $500 in profit? So for example for sake of argument would I get like 2.8 ETH if it makes up for the $500 profit?

Comment: @lungj, when I go to exchange the OMG tokens for Ethereum with my $500 profit in OMG, will I receive $500 more worth of Ethereum coins now to make up for that $500 profit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a longer comment more than an answer. I'm hiding the trading account normally used for book-keeping.

```
At T=1
Prices:
    X = $100
    Y = $50
    Z = $1000

Holdings: $100.   Value: $100 == 1 X == 2 Y == 0.1 Z.

Transaction: Sell $100 for 1 X.
Holdings: 1 X.    Value: $100 == 1 X == 2 Y == 0.1 Z.

At T=2
    X = $150
    Y = $50
    Z = $1000

Holdings: 1 X.    Value: $150 == 1 X == 3 Y == 0.15 Z.

Transaction: Sell 1 X for 3 Y.

Holdings: 3 Y.    Value: $150 == 1 X == 3 Y == 0.15 Z.

At T=3
    X = $300
    Y = $100
    Z = $1500

Holdings: 3 Y.    Value: $300 == 1 X == 3 Y == 0.3 Z.

At T=4
    X = $30
    Y = $25
    Z = $2500

Holdings: 3 Y.    Value: $75 == 2.5 X == 3 Y == 0.01 Z.

Transaction: Sell 3 Y for 2.5 X.
Holdings: 2.5 X.  Value: $75 == 2.5 X == 3 Y == 0.01 Z.
```

Note that at the last step, you have more X than you had at T=1, but you actually have less $ than at T=1. If X is GBP and you're from England, you've still come out ahead of the game (even if you could have done better simply by holding $) since you now have more GBP relative to what you had before.

As you can hopefully see, this question has nothing to do with Ethereum.

Comment: I don't really understand this comment of yours, can you just answer my question directly with a YES or NO answer?  when I go to exchange the OMG tokens for Ethereum with my $500 profit in OMG, will I receive $500 more worth of Ethereum coins now to make up for that $500 profit?

Comment: Your "make up for that $500 profit" makes no sense, accounting-wise. You might be better served by having someone at https://money.stackexchange.com explain forex trading accounts or replicating portfolios.

Comment: So if I buy $2000 worth of ETH, then in Binance exchange it to equivalent amount of OMG tokens lets say 3000. Then in etherscan it says that the value of my tokens have risen by $500 so it's now $2500. If I go to exchange the $2500 worth of OMG in Binance back to ETH coins, do I not receive extra Ethereum coins that show the $500 profit?

Comment: It depends what the price of ETH is. The $500 profit is denominated in $. You're asking about a price in ETH. If the ETH/$ pair has gone up more than than the OMG/$ pair since the exchange from ETH to OMG, then you will receive less ETH. I.e., the thing that matters for how much Ether you receive is the ETH/OMG pair.

Comment: Ok lets say I bought the $2000 worth of 2.5 ETH at ETH price of $860. So when I go to exchange the OMG back to ETH with my extra $500 profit, would I receive like 2.7 ETH ( for example) which would amount to that 0.2 ETH = $500 profit?

Comment: Even if I receive less ETH by the time I sell that ETH in GDAX, will it still be worth more ($500 more) than what I initially paid for it assuming the price of ETH was the same when I buy it and sell it in GDAX?

Comment: "$2000 worth of 2.5 ETH at ETH price of $860" -- I think there's a math error here. $2000 worth of ETH at $860 is ~2.32 ETH. 2.5 ETH at $860 is $2150-worth of ETH. And what is the final price of ETH, in USD in your example? I will post a follow-up comment with an example that I hope answers your question.

Comment: I was only giving an example, not giving you precise value of ETH to USD. I didn't do any math on it, it was just purely for example standpoint.

Comment: Point is, if according to etherscan the value of my OMG token has increased by $500. I'm just asking that by the time I do the exchange between OMG/ETH and sell the ETH in GDAX, if for the sake of argument the price of ETH I buy for and sell for are both $860, would I still receive the extra $500 that I made when I sell the ETH to USD?

Comment: If you bought $8000 worth of ETH at $800, you have 10 ETH. If you exchange that to OMG and the price of OMG is 40 OMG/ETH (1 OMG=$20),  you now 0 ETH and 400 OMG. Liquidating this is $8000. If OMG rises in price to $25 and the price of ETH rises to $1000, then you have $10 000 of OMG tokens (profit of $2000). However, notice that you have made 0 ETH profit (your OMG still only buys 10 ETH).

Comment: it won't be 0 ETH, it'll be like 0.345 or 0.044 or something smaller that'll be equivalent to the OMG when traded right? so will the ETH show any profit when I sell it in GDAX to USD?

Comment: In the situation I just described, it is 0 ETH. If you bought $8000 worth of ETH at $800, you have 10 ETH. If you exchange that to OMG and the price of OMG is 40 OMG/ETH (1 OMG=$20), you now 0 ETH and 400 OMG. Liquidating this is $8000. If OMG rises in price to $25 then you have $10 000 of OMG tokens (profit of $2000). If the price of Ethereum is still $800, THEN you will see a 2.5 ETH profit. But no matter ETH's price (assuming efficient markets and no commission/spread), your 400 OMG, when you sell it for Ether and then sell the Ether for $, you will have a profit of $2000.

Comment: That's all I was asking for thank you for taking your time to help me. Best of luck to you and your cryptocurrency trades and investments.